# Open download form with java http request

Tags: java, http

I have a little problem and I'm going mad. I have tomcat 6. I put a `.docx` file into

```
$CATALINA_HOME/webapp/root
```

then I start server with

```
$CTALINA_HOME/bin/startup.bat
```

and if (in a browser) I go to `http://localhost:8080/prova.docx` the open/download file prompt appears.

Now I want to connect in some way to that address with java and I want the same result. I searched with google anyway but nothing seems work.

Answer (score 0):

The open/download file prompt is a browser functionnality, so you won't get that in your Java program. If what you want is only to download the data from the URL, have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html. Java provides the URLConnection class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) which is what you need.